# Operator vs Anonymous function precedence in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, syntax, anonymous-function, operator-precedence

In Haskell the following expression:

```
 a \b -> c $ d
```

is either

• Invalid

• `(a (\b ->c)) d`

• `(a (\b -> (c d))`

And why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s invalid in vanilla Haskell because a lambda cannot be used directly as an argument to a function without an intervening operator. The correct version needs to use `$` or parentheses:

```
a   \b -> c $ d
a $ \b -> c $ d
a ( \b -> c $ d )
```

However, there is no fundamental reason that a lambda (or `case`, `if`, `do`, or `let` expression) should not be allowed there, because it’s not ambiguous. The `BlockArguments` extension (added in [GHC 8.6.1](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/8.6.1-notes.html#language)) allows these syntactic constructs directly as arguments to functions. With that enabled, it parses the same as above, as:

```
(a (\b -> (c $ d))
```

The reason this does *not* parse as *`(a (\b -> c)) d` is that the scope of a lambda is defined in the [Haskell Report §3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#expressions) as extending as far rightward as possible (emphasis added):

> The grammar is ambiguous regarding **the extent of lambda abstractions, let expressions, and conditionals**. The ambiguity is resolved by the meta-rule that **each of these constructs extends as far to the right as possible.**

In other words, the body of the lambda can be thought of as having *lower* precedence than any other expression. This notation is borrowed directly from lambda calculus, in which *a* λ*b*. *c* *d* is the same as (*a* (λ*b*. (*c* *d*))).

Note that I haven’t removed the `$` here: these two expressions are different, even though they evaluate to the same result:

```
f x
f $ x
```

The first is an application of the function `f` to the argument `x`; the second is an application of the operator `($)` to the arguments `f` and `x`. Like all infix operators, it’s syntactic sugar for a normal prefix function call:

```
($) f x
```

`($)` is defined as a right-associative operator (i.e. `x $ y $ z` = `x $ (y $ z)`, *not* *`(x $ y) $ z`) with the lowest operator precedence, with the declaration `infixr 0` in the `Prelude`. You can view information about an operator with the `:info` (or `:i`) command in GHCi:

```
> :info $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 0 $
```